# Transmogrify into date from multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql, string, date

What is a better way to program the following SQL:

```
str_to_date(
  concat(convert(D.DAY, CHAR(2)),
  '-',
  convert(M.MONTH, CHAR(2)),
  '-',
  convert(M.YEAR, CHAR(4))),
  '%e-%m-%Y' ) as AMOUNT_DATE
```

I want to convert the columns `D.DAY`, `M.MONTH`, and `M.YEAR` to a date field using MySQL. The above works, but seems much more complicated than it needs to be. (If there's an ANSI SQL way to do it, that would be even better.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small improvement you can make is using [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead of `CONCAT` (the "WS" stands for "with separator"--it's the equivalent of `join` or `implode` in other languages). And MySQL should automatically convert the arguments to strings, so the `CONVERT` functions are, I believe, unnecessary.

```
STR_TO_DATE(
  CONCAT_WS('-', D.DAY, M.MONTH, M.YEAR),
  '%e-%m-%Y'
) AS AMOUNT_DATE
```

I'm guessing this doesn't perform as well as Tomalak's arithmetic solution, though.

Comment: Thank you. This solution looks easier to read, but probably not as fast.

Comment: +1 because this will fail at invalid dates, mine will not. Better safe than sorry, I would prefer this solution being accepted.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
DATE_ADD(
  DATE_ADD(
    MAKEDATE(M.YEAR,1),
    INTERVAL M.MONTH-1 MONTH
  ), 
  INTERVAL D.DAY-1 DAY
)
```

Comment: @Dave and it's pure math, no string-juggling, so it should be reasonably fast. Still, I'm not at home at MySQL, so there could be a better way to do the same. Also note that this implies that the DAY/MONTH/YEAR columns always make sense together, because this returns a false positive for `31,2,2010`!

Comment: The data has already been sanitized against false dates. Thanks again!